# Apache 2.4.27 mod_rewrite to cgi-bin fails

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, cgi-bin

Apache 2.4.27 on Oracle Linux 7 x64.

I can make proper calls to `https://example.com/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi`.
The simple Perl script returns "Hello, world via cgi-bin!"

I can make proper calls to static content in `https://example.com/helloworld.html`
The simple HTML file returns "Hello, world via html!"

I can use `RewriteRule` as:

```
RewriteRule "^/test" "/helloworld.html"
```

I see "Hello, world via html!"

However, I cannot use RewriteRule as:

```
RewriteRule "^/test" "/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi"
```

This results in a 400 Bad Request. How is it that I can call it directly though?

How do I get my `RewriteRule` to work when going to `/cgi-bin`? That seems to be my problem. I tried adding `[L]` and `[L,PT]` but no help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what can be wrong in your configuration, how do you have `ScriptAlias` env set ?

I have tested with configuration below and everything seems to be fine on Apache 2.4.10 :

```
<VirtualHost 10.44.0.3:80>

    DocumentRoot "/vat/www/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mysite.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/mysite.example.com-access_log" common

    ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/mysite/cgi-bin/"

    <Directory "/var/www/mysite">
          Require all granted
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride all
    </Directory>


    <Directory "/var/www/mysite/cgi-bin">
          Options +ExecCGI
          AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </Directory>


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^/test" "/cgi-bin/test.cgi"

</VirtualHost>
```

opening http://mysite.exmaple.com/test opens up the cgi script

Comment: I think this may have to do with the fact that my RewriteRule was inside of my <Directory> and putting it outside, seems to help.  The cgi-bin isnt my code, but it doesnt return 404/400...  I get some app specific stuff.  I THINK this fixes it, but I am emailing app people to test.  Thank you for your help.  I will update with a final answer soon

Comment: @AaronG If your `RewriteRule` was inside a `<Directory>` container then your first test (`RewriteRule "^/test" "/helloworld.html"`) also wouldn't have worked? But neither would this directive have resulted in a 400 response, as it simply would not have done anything - the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would not match inside a `<Directory>` container. So, there would seem to be _something else_ going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I add the same problem. When I used:

```
RewriteRule "^/test" "/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi"
```

It didn't work. I had to use `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` to check the logs. In my case, the rewritten path was being prefixed with document_root. So, instead of `/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi` I was getting `/var/www/html/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi`.

To solve the issue, I used two flags:

```
RewriteRule "^/test" "/cgi-bin/helloworld.cgi" [NC,PT]
```

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065739/mod-rewrite-rewrite-url-to-point-to-cgi-script-but-keep-rewrite-hidden/30067581#30067581